# Перенос строки в textarea

Tags: javascript, html, события

Всем привет!
В область `<teaxtarea>` вводится текст. Необходимо чтобы при **клике** на определенную кнопку(пусть называется "Enter") осуществлялся перенос строки в выбранной области. Я попробовал использовать такое выражение `area.value=area.value+'\r\n'`, но строка переноситься без значения.

```js
let enter = document.querySelector('.key')
enter.addEventListener('click', handleClick)

function handleClick(event){
     const action = event.target
     area.value=area.value+'\r\n'
}
```

```html
<textarea name="screen" id="area" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Введите данные с клавиатуры" autofocus></textarea>

<div class="key enter" data-action="13">Enter</div>
 </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let enter = document.querySelector('.key')
enter.addEventListener('click', handleClick)

function handleClick(event) {
  area.value = 
    area.value.substring(0, area.selectionStart) + 
    "\n" +
    area.value.substring(area.selectionEnd, area.value.length);
}
```

```html
<textarea name="screen" id="area" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Введите данные с клавиатуры" autofocus></textarea>

<div class="key enter" data-action="13">Enter</div>
</div>
```

Comment: СПАСИБЫ ВАМ! ВЫ ЛУЧШИЙ!

Comment: А с пробелом тоже самое сделать можно? Только использовать вместо /n - символ \t?

Comment: @AzetX Можно. Только `"\t"` - это табуляция, а не пробел.

Comment: Я просто прочитал, что символ \b (backspace) сейчас не используются. Поэтому думал можно заменить  \t

Comment: @AzetX Не понял.

Comment: Процитирую из учебника)
 "\b, \f, \v  - Backspace, Form Feed и Vertical Tab — оставлены для обратной совместимости, сейчас не используются." 
https://learn.javascript.ru/string

Comment: @AzetX А пробел здесь при чем?

Comment: \b разве не считается символом пробела?

Comment: @AzetX Вы же сами написали - "Backspace" (удаление символа слева от курсора). Пробел - `" "`.

Comment: Хорошо. Понял. Спасибо еще раз большое!

Comment: @AzetX Пожалуйста. Успехов.